# Firestore join issues

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In some case like user's profile picture which is constantly edit is impossible to denormalize. If I do denormalize it will need to update quite a lot of document and subcollection. In firebase database I can just simply perform join query, but in firestore there is a problem which firestore charge by read, write or delete. Is there any better way to resolve this problem?